# Postgresql: two columns the same but third column different, display rows

Tags: postgresql

I have 4 columns id, firstname, last name, reference. Most times the reference is the same but I need to display each row that has the same names, but a different reference in postgresql and order them by the id number. ONLY for those rows which someone has more than one reference. I've tried a bunch of things but just made a mess. Please assist.
For example:-

```
20 / John / Smith / 675  
21 / John / Smith / 675  
22 / John / Smith / 676  
22 / Joe  / Bloggs/ 651  
24 / Joe  / Bloggs/ 651  
25 / John / Smith / 674
```

Should return all the John Smith rows, because one or more of his references is dissimilar

```
20 / John / Smith / 675  
21 / John / Smith / 675  
22 / John / Smith / 676  
25 / John / Smith / 674
```

I can use this to get a count, but I want to display the full rows

```
    select firstname, lastname, count (distinct id)
    from transfer
    group by firstname, lastname
    having count(distinct id) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to count, you only have to check if (at least) one record with a different value for `reference` for the same person exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM transfer t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM transfer x
  WHERE x.firstname = t.firstname     -- same name
    AND x.lastname = t.lastname
    AND x. reference <> t.reference   -- different reference
  );
```

Comment: Both answers work, this is the better one for what I need I think

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible answer:

```
select id, firstname, lastname, reference
from transfer t1
where 1 < (select count(distinct reference) 
           from transfer t2
           where t1.firstname = t2.firstname and t1.lastname = t2.lastname)
```

Comment: doesn't return anything when I try it in phppgadmin

Comment: @Kilisi, when I try the query, it returns all the rows with John Smith. Please post the table definition. This is my table: `create table transfer (id integer, firstname text,lastname text, reference integer);` and I inserted the 6 rows of your example.

Comment: mine is the same, except reference is char varying, don't see how that would impact on it though. Seems to just crash in phppgadmin... I'll try it again when I get to my office tomorrow

Comment: @Kilisi, there was an error in my answer, it should have been `(distinct reference)`, not `(distinct id)`. I have now edited the query.